# Ordering by MethodSerializer

Tags: python, django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer that has a methodfield popular such as it returns a specific float. Is there a way to order by the serializermethodfield?

Code Snippets:

**serializers.py**

```
class PostListSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    popular = serializers.SerializerMethodField('popularity')

    def popularity(self, obj):
        time = datetime.datetime.now()
        n = obj.created.replace(tzinfo=None)
        r = time.replace(tzinfo=None)
        x = r - n
        a = float(str(x.total_seconds()//(60*60*24)))
        view = obj.post.count()
        return view / a
```

**views.py**

```
class PopularPostsSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostListSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.OrderingFilter,)
    ordering_fields = ('popular')
```

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I'm pretty sure the answer is no, as the `popularity` function cannot be used in the query.

Comment: @OozeMeister any idea how I can go about this?

Comment: Actually, I retract what I said. It's not working?
`/api/v1/postlist?ordering=popular` doesn't sort by popular?

Comment: @OozeMeister nope, doesn't seem to be working at all

Answer (score 0):

Filter backends are based on changing the queryset. So they only work for fields in the database, not calculated fields.

So you I see two possibilities:

- put the popularity into the database, update it when saving the `Post` or other data changes that the number depends on.
- sort the result yourself. Just override `list` in the viewset, read the ordering-argument yourself and sort the results you get from calling `list` from your parent.

Comment: @denniscornehl can you give me an example on how I'd go about the first one?